# How to find the length of maximum subarray sum in segment tree query?

Tags: algorithms, graphs, trees, maximum-subarray, suffix-array

> Problem: Given an array with size$\ n  $: for each$\ a[i] $, it denotes the value of the house. You are given the task to build the wall that saves the house that is not exceed$\ w $ length. What is the maximum value you can save?

Constraint:

$\ 1<=n<=6,000,000 $;

$\ -500,000<=a[i]<=500,000  $;

$\ 1<=w<=100,000  $;
[image]

*For instance: n = 7, w = 3*

3 2 *5 1 4* -7 **10**

```
So the maximum value will be 10 and the maximum size will be
1 (10) or 3 (5 1 4).

but the answer must be the minimum of length if there are more than one possible answers.

So the length will be 1.
```

Is there anyway to achieve this using segment tree?

---

I have tried: Maximum subsegment sum using the prefix and suffix sum. But I cannot find the length.

Comment: Welcome to [cs.SE]! Could you please format your question as text (and not a bullet point list) so it is more understandable? Also, I believe your question would benefit greatly from adding some more context (i.e., *why* is it an interesting question?). Thank you.

Comment: What is $q$ and how does it relate to this problem? Why do you want to use a segment tree? I feel this could be done easily with a sliding window implemented as a [deque](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Double-ended_queue). What have you tried so far, in regards to using a segment tree?

Comment: Please edit the question to add a reference to the original problem you are asked to solve. A reference is especially helpful to avoid ambiguities and XY problem.

Comment: Is this a problem in an **ongoing programming contest**?

Comment: No. this is the problem 2 years ago in my country.

Comment: I know the (best) solution to this problem. However, I would like to know how/why you "cannot find the length" even though you can get "maximum subarray sum". Can you edit the question to explain how you get the "maximum subarray sum"?

Comment: I do not know how to implement the length.

Comment: If you know how to get the "maximum subarray sum", then you can also get the subarray length since you can record the subarray length together with the maximum subarray sum.

Comment: Is there other possible solution other than segment tree?

Comment: Can this be solved using amortized analysis with kadane in O(n)?